# RSpec test with factory_girl and will_paginate for associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, will-paginate

I am having problems with writing a test in rspec for will_paginate. The problem is that I have a model with an Owner that can have many pets. This leads to a factories.rb file that looks like this:

```
Factory.define :owner do |owner|
  owner.personid              "1111111"
  owner.firstname             "Nisse"
  owner.lastname              "Gunnarsson"
  owner.street                "Street"
  owner.postaladress          "38830"
  owner.town                  "Town"
  owner.phone                 "555-5555"
  owner.mobile                "555-5556"
  owner.email                 "nisse@test.com"
  owner.reminder              true
end

Factory.define :pet do |pet|
  pet.name                    "Hedvig"
  pet.specie                  "Rabbot"
  pet.breed                   "Lowen/vadur"
  pet.colour                  "Madagaskar"
  pet.association             :owner
end
```

In my test I have

```
describe "Get show" do
  before(:each) do
  @owner = Factory(:owner)
  30.times do
    #@owner.pets << Factory.build(:pet)
    @pet = Factory.build(:pet, :owner => @owner)
    #@owner.pets << @pet
  end      
end

it "should have an element for each pet" do
   get :show, :id => @owner
   @owner.pets[0..2].each do |pet|
     response.should have_selector("td", :content => pet.name)
   end
   response.should have_selector("td", :content => "Hedvig")
 end

 it "should paginate pets" do
   get :show, :id => @owner
   response.should have_selector("div.pagination")
   response.should have_selector("span.disabled", :content => "Previous")
   response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/pets?page=2",
                                      :content => "2")
   response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/pets?page=2",
                                      :content => "Next")
 end
```

end

So I create an Owner with the factory, no problem there. I can get the owners name by `puts @owner.firstname`

I can also create a pet, that has the correct owner (`@pet.owner.firstname`), but I can not figure out how to fill the owners array (@owner.pets) with pets.

If I do a @owner.pets.count it is 0.

The applications works fine, I just can't figure out how to write the test. I am really new to both rails and TDD but I want to do it right.

Let me know if I should add more information.

Cheers Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first, doing `@pet = Factory.build(:pet, :owner => @owner)` only builds a Pet object, but never saves it to the DB. You would want to use `Factory.create(:pet, ...` to get it to actually save.

The `@owner.pets` array is [] when you initially create the Owner object. If you simply create records in the DB with `Factory.create` then yes, technically `@owner` has pets, but the `@owner` object doesn't know about them because it's already in memory with a `.pets` array of [].

Instead, try this:

```
@owner.pets << Factory.create(:pet, :owner => @owner)
```

That will not only save it to the database, thus making any new calls to the database valid (such as now if you did `Pet.count` you'd get back 1) but also the `@owner.pets` array in memory will have a valid Pet object within it.

Comment: Brilliant! This solved it. I guess I still have a lot to learn. (which is kinda fun). Thanks a million!