# Testing will paginate gem with Rspec/Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, pagination, capybara

In my application there is an admin part, which is restricted to superadmins (users with a property `superadmin: true`). I've got a shop list, which I want to get paginated and tested.

When debugging the current code with `save_and_open_page` I get a blank page. If I log in not as a superadmin, I get redirected to application's root and when trying to debug with `save_and_open_page` is see the root page.. If I do not log in at all, then I'll get redirected to the sign in page. So the basic functionality should work.

I'm having no clue why it does not work with `superadmin` and why I do not see the shops list when debugging with `save_and_open_page`.

This is my `spec/controllers/shops_controller_spec.rb` (copied basically from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77180/rspec-test-for-pagination)) :

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Admin::ShopsController, type: :controller do

  context "GET methods" do

    describe "#index action" do
      before(:all) {  
        amount = Rails.application.config.page_size
        amount.times { FactoryGirl.create(:shop) }
      }

      before(:each) {
        login_as(FactoryGirl.create(:user, superadmin: true), :scope => :user)
      }

      context "with entries == config.page_size" do
        it "has no second page" do
          get :index
          expect(response).not_to have_selector("a", :href => "/shops?page=2", :content => "2")
          # visit admin_shops_path
          # expect(page).to have_no_xpath("//*[@class='pagination']//a[text()='2']")
        end
      end

      context "with entries > config.page_size" do
        before { FactoryGirl.create(:shop) }

        it "has a second page with too many entries" do 
          visit "/admin/shops"
          save_and_open_page
          expect(page).to have_xpath("//*[@class='pagination']//a[text()='2']")
        end

        it "correctly redirects to next page" do
          visit admin_shops_path
          find("//*[@class='pagination']//a[text()='2']").click
          expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, I tried to test in different ways (the "expect block" is taken from [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692399/rspec-test-with-factory-girl-and-will-paginate-for-associated-objects?rq=1)), but none of them work. Using `get :index` I receive

```
Admin::ShopsController GET methods #index action with entries == config.page_size has no second page
     Failure/Error: expect(page).not_to have_selector("a", :href => "/shops?page=2", :content => "2")

     ArgumentError:
       invalid keys :href, :content, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :id, :class, :visible, :exact, :exact_text, :match, :wait, :filter_set
```

Here is my AdminController.rb if it helps:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
    layout 'admin'

  before_action :authenticate_user!, :verify_is_superadmin

    before_action :set_locale
    before_action :get_breadcrumbs

    private

    def get_breadcrumbs
        splitted_url = request.original_fullpath.split("/")
        # Remove first object
        splitted_url.shift
        result = splitted_url.map { |element| element.humanize.capitalize }
        session[:breadcrumbs] = result
        # debug
    end

    def set_locale
        I18n.locale =  params[:locale] || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
        # session[:locale] = I18n.locale
    end

  def verify_is_superadmin
    (current_user.nil?) ? redirect_to(root_path) : (redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.superadmin?)
  end

end
```

**Update**
Using Thomas' answer I ended up putting my code in `spec/features` and it looks like this right now:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Widget management", :type => :feature do

  before(:each) {  
    amount = Rails.application.config.page_size
    amount.times { FactoryGirl.create(:shop) }
  }

  before(:each) {
    login_as(FactoryGirl.create(:user, superadmin: true), :scope => :user)
  }

  scenario "with entries == config.page_size" do

    visit admin_shops_path
    #save_and_open_page
    expect(page).to have_no_xpath("//*[@class='pagination']//a[text()='2']")
  end

  scenario "with entries > config.page_size" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:shop)
    visit admin_shops_path
    expect(page).to have_xpath("//*[@class='pagination']//a[text()='2']")
  end

  scenario "with entries > config.page_size it correctly redirects to next page" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:shop)
    visit admin_shops_path
    find("//*[@class='pagination']//a[text()='2']").click
    expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

Everything works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a number of issues here.

Firstly the other SO question you linked to isn't using Capybara so copying its examples for matchers is wrong.

Secondly you are writing controller tests, not view tests or feature tests. controller tests don't render the page by default, so to test elements on the page you want to be writing either view tests or feature tests. Capybara is designed for feature tests and isn't designed for controller tests. This is why the default `capybara/rspec` configuration file only includes the Capybara DSL into tests of type 'feature'.  It also includes the Capybara RSpec matchers into view tests since they are useful with the rendered strings provided there.

Thirdly, you are mixing usage of `get/response`, and `visit/page` in the same file which just confuses things.

If you rewrite these as feature tests, then to check you don't have a link with a specific href in capybara you would do

```
expect(page).not_to have_link(href: '...')
```

If you want to make sure that a link doesn't exist with specific text and a specific href

```
expect(page).not_to have_link('link text', href: '...')
```

Note: that checks there is not a link with both the given text and the given href, there could still be links with the text or the href

Comment: Thanks you! Putting everything in spec/features really did solve the issue. I mixed `get/response` and `visit/page` on purpose to try to get working at least one test case.